# GO validate access token (keycloak)

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, oauth, keycloak

I am trying to implement access token validation with GO. But the examples I see online only seem to validate it with the TOKEN_SECRET. however I am used to programming in Java spring and there I dont need to use TOKEN_SECRET. I just provide the jwk-set-uri and it checks the validity (automatically - security filters and such) I know that it comunicates with the oauth server and makes this validation.

Is there no lib in Go that checks that the token is valid with a request to the oauth server?

Right know I know that I can make it manually with a request to the user info endpoint of the oauth server:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

(include token in the headers with key Authorization)

but I don't know if this is exacly following standards.

What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use [go-oidc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/coreos/go-oidc/v3/oidc)

Long answer:
First, let's understand how Spring Security automatically validates access tokens that are JWTs. By convention, if you define OAuth 2.0 or OIDC client properties in the `application.yaml` config file, Spring will automatically wire a filter in the security filter chain that fetches `jwk-set` from Keycloak which is a set of public keys corresponding to the secret keys used by Keycloak to sign the tokens. This filter will applied to all protected routes and spring will use the public key to check if the signature of the token is valid and make additional checks if applicable (audience, time-out, etc...)

So how do we do this in Go? We can write a simple middleware that accepts the `jwk-set` and use it to validate the tokens. You will need to check the `alg` claim to see which signing algorithm was used, pick the corresponding public key from `jwk-set` and check that the signature is valid. Then, decode the token, confirm the `iss` and `sub` claims to ensure it's from a trusted issuer and for the intended audience, and check that it hasn't expired. Check the `nbf` (Not Before) and `iat` (Issued At) claims for correct timing. Finally, inject relevant info from the token to the request context if needed downstream.

```
func JWTMiddleware(jwkSet map[string]*rsa.PublicKey) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            authHeader := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
            if authHeader == "" {
                http.Error(w, "Authorization header is required", http.StatusUnauthorized)
                return
            }

            tokenString := strings.TrimPrefix(authHeader, "Bearer ")
            token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
                if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
                }

                alg := token.Method.Alg()
                publicKey, ok := jwkSet[alg]
                if !ok {
                    return nil, fmt.Errorf("no key found for signing method: %v", alg)
                }
                return publicKey, nil
            })
            
            if err != nil || !token.Valid {
                http.Error(w, "Invalid token", http.StatusUnauthorized)
                return
            }
            // Other checks, ISS, Aud, Expirey, etc ...
            // If needed, store the user principal 
            // and other relevant info the request context  
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I would change in your answer — you should validate the signature first, then check the other claims. You actually do it like that in the code example. Just the text mentions it the other way.

Comment: Thanks Michal for pointing that out. Adjusted it!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify your understanding.

> I know that it comunicates with the oauth server and makes this validation.

Not exactly. What it does is it calls Keycloak's JWKS endpoint once to get the public keys. It caches them and then uses them to perform offline validation of the token — verify the signature and some claims, like expiration. So, once Spring has the public keys it will not call Keycloak again (unless the keys need to be refreshed).

> Right know I know that I can make it manually with a request to the user info endpoint of the oauth server:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<your_realm>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
> ```
>
> (include token in the headers with key Authorization)

You could do that, but now you will be calling the authorization server on every request to your application. JWT was designed in a way so that it can be used offline. The solution you now have, based on adel's answer, is the one you should use.

Comment: yes yes, thank you for the further explanaition! I understood it from adel's awnser, but further explanation is always welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

So the awnser by adel seems to be correct, but I was not able to use the lib he pointed to. Also it seemed to need a few extra steps to work correctly with keycloak.

I ended up using
[golang-jwt/jwt/v5](https://%20%20github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v5)

I am also using Gin so the midleware structure is diferent:

```
func JWTMiddleware(jwkSet map[string]*rsa.PublicKey) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        authHeader := c.GetHeader("Authorization")

        if authHeader == "" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": "Authorization header is required"})
            c.Abort()
            return
        }

        tokenString := strings.TrimPrefix(authHeader, "Bearer ")
        token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
            }

            // Extract the key ID (kid) from the token header
            kid, ok := token.Header["kid"].(string)
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("kid not found in token header")
            }

            // Retrieve the public key from the JWK set using the key ID
            publicKey, keyExists := jwkSet[kid]
            if !keyExists {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("public key not found for kid: %v", kid)
            }

            return publicKey, nil
        })

        if err != nil || !token.Valid {
            c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": "Invalid token"})
            c.Abort()
            return
        }

        // Extract the mainId claim from the token
        mainIDStr, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)["mainId"].(string)
        if !ok {
            c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": "mainId not found in token"})
            c.Abort()
            return
        }

        // Convert the mainId string to an integer
        mainID, err := strconv.Atoi(mainIDStr)
        if err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Error converting mainId to integer"})
            c.Abort()
            return
        }

        // Store the mainId in the request context
        c.Set("mainId", mainID)

        // Continue with the next middleware or route handler
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

This is the function to get the JWTset from a keycloak endpoint:

```
// GetJWKSet retrieves the JWK set from the specified URL and returns a map of RSA public keys.
func GetJWKSet(url string) (map[string]*rsa.PublicKey, error) {
    // Make the GET request
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error making GET request: %v", err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    // Decode the JSON response
    var jwkSet struct {
        Keys []struct {
            Kid string   `json:"kid"`
            N   string   `json:"n"`
            E   string   `json:"e"`
            X5C []string `json:"x5c"`
        } `json:"keys"`
    }
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(response.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&jwkSet); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decoding JSON: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a map to store RSA public keys
    jwkMap := make(map[string]*rsa.PublicKey)

    // Iterate through each key in the JWK set
    for _, key := range jwkSet.Keys {
        // Decode base64url-encoded modulus (N) and exponent (E)
        modulus, err := decodeBase64URL(key.N)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decoding modulus: %v", err)
        }

        exponent, err := decodeBase64URL(key.E)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error decoding exponent: %v", err)
        }

        // Create RSA public key
        pubKey := &rsa.PublicKey{
            N: modulus,
            E: int(exponent.Int64()),
        }

        // Store the public key in the map using the key ID (Kid)
        jwkMap[key.Kid] = pubKey
    }

    return jwkMap, nil
}

// decodeBase64URL decodes a base64url-encoded string and returns a big.Int
func decodeBase64URL(input string) (*big.Int, error) {
    // Convert base64url to base64
    base64Str := strings.ReplaceAll(input, "-", "+")
    base64Str = strings.ReplaceAll(base64Str, "_", "/")

    // Pad the base64 string with "="
    switch len(base64Str) % 4 {
    case 2:
        base64Str += "=="
    case 3:
        base64Str += "="
    }

    // Decode base64 string
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(base64Str)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Convert bytes to big.Int
    result := new(big.Int).SetBytes(data)
    return result, nil
}
```